# Invalid username or password on Android lock screen when 2 step verification is enabled

Tags: lock-screens

I have a Moto G (1st gen) running Kitkat 4.4.4 (not rooted). The first time I signed into my Google account on my device I had 2 step verification enabled. I still do have it enabled. Now in the “forgot password” screen I’m not able to sign in using my id and password.

I haven’t changed my password in a year so I’m positive that I had the same password at that time which I have now. When I tried signing in with an application specific password, it worked out but only when I was connected to the internet.

So the question arises what should I do if I’m offline and by any chance get locked out because of kids messing with the lock screen. And yes when I disabled 2 step verification I was able to sign in with my actual password when connected to the internet but still not able to sign in when offline. Any kind of help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

In the username field are you providing the entire email address i.e. shubham@gmail.com or only shubham? The login works better if the email is provided.

Also if you are offline and got locked out from the phone, the only option is hard reset. If you were rooted and have USB Debugging enabled then it's a different story.

But if your connected to wifi or if mobile data is on, then the forgot pattern (or similar) would be working.

Comment: Yes I do type in the full email address. And I'm not locked out (yet). I just want to know what my password is when I'm offline (sounds strange: me asking you'll my password :P) Thanks for the response!